# Is it necessary to call [super encodeWithCoder] when subclassing a object that implements NSCoding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscoding

I know that when you write the initWithCoder method of a subclass of an object that implements NSCoding you have to call super `initWithCoder` (instead of `super init`), but do I have to call `super encodeWithCoder` in the implementation of encodeWithCoder?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you inherit from a class that supports Encoding, it is generally adviseable to use `[super encodeWithCoder:]` in your `encodeWithCoder:` method, as much as `[super initWithCoder:]` is to be used in the `initWithCoder:` method.

**Documentation :** [NSCoding Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

**Reference :** http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSCoder

> if the class inherits from a Class that conforms to 
>   (NSObject does not conform) then you should include the [encodeWithCoder:] method.

```
//  <NSCoding> protocol methods

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
    [super encodeWithCoder:coder];
    /*
    [coder encodeObject: theNSStringInstanceVariable];
    [coder encodeObject: theNSDictionaryInstanceVariable];
    [coder encodeValueOfObjCType:@encode(BOOL) at:&theBooleanInstanceVariable];
    [coder encodeValueOfObjCType:@encode(float) at:&theFloatInstanceVariable];
    */
}
```